# How to get error code in custom bootstrapper WiX 3.8

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.8

I am using c# custom bootstrapper in WiX.But i am not getting error code if any fatal error occurs while installation.I think ApplyComplete should return errror code.Please help.

Comment: Can you show error code also in your question?

Comment: For example :Error code 0x80070642 represents User cancelled installation

Comment: Show full code of error in your question.